# (React webpack) Files under the src folder are not loaded when run project on development mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm new in React.js. I created project with 'create-react-app' command. I wanted to add server, so eject project. But files that located under the **src** folder don't appear on localhost:4000. I can see contents in index.html. What is my problem?

Here is my **package.json** scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node --presets=es2015 ./server/main.js --watch server"
}
```

And this is **webpack.dev.config.js**

```
  var webpack = require('webpack');
    var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {

    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/index.js',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:4000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/style.css'
    ],

    output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './public',
        proxy: {
            "*": "http://localhost:3000"
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],

    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve("./src"), 'node_modules']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                })],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the application load correctly on port 4000?
Do you want to list the content of src directory?

Comment: @bonheury No I want to see src/index.js contents(App.js) not list. I can see only html content in public directory. Isn't webpack.module.entry access './src/index.js' as I wrote in code?

Comment: I don't think that the entry './src/index.js' is the issue. Did you load the script file `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` in the index.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack-dev-server loads only the content of `index.html` because it doesn’t see the bundle file `bundle.js`. In your configuration, the destination of the bundle file is the directory `'/'`.

```
 output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
```

But `webpack-dev-server` serve contents from `'./public'` directory (`contentBase: './public'`). You should tell webpack to look at public directory and root directory like this

```
devServer: {
        hot: true,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: ['/', '/public'],
        proxy: {
            "*": "http://localhost:3000"
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to reference the bundle file in index.html.

Comment: YES @bonheury I did big mistake! I didn't add `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` file on my html file... And I change code as you point. Thank you